# Auth0 User could not login with original password after I export/import them to new connection

Tags: react-native, auth0, auth0-lock, auth0-connection, auth0-js

I have 2 database connection namely SPI, and SPF. I imported successfully to my SPF database from SPI. So now when I search for ‘ehruniza_92@yahoo.com’ I can see it is available in this 2 connections. also I have set my app to use SPF only as connection.

```
[
  {"user_id":"auth0|65113c86a6b90e141ecc144e",
  "email":"ehruniza_92@yahoo.com",
  "name":"ehruniza_92@yahoo.com",
  "nickname":"ehruniza_92",
  "logins_count":14,
  "created_at":"2023-09-25T07:53:42.567Z",
  "updated_at":"2023-10-09T03:09:36.447Z",
  "last_login":"2023-10-09T03:09:36.447Z",
  "email_verified":false},

  .......
]
```

But now my app using SPF, I could not log in using ‘ehruniza_92@yahoo.com’ email. I keep getting wrong username/password. I realize there is not password in json file generated by export. How can i export users and also get their password. isn’t Auth0 should generate the password also when exporting?

I have also asked in auth0 community https://community.auth0.com/t/user-could-not-login-with-original-password-after-i-export-import-them-to-new-connection/118472?u=developers9

Thank you